# Choosing between recursion or iteration

Tags: recursion, iteration, common-lisp

I am currently trying to solve this task in Common Lisp :

-Make a function that when given three parameters (u r n) returns the average of the "n" first terms of a geometric sequence defined by its first term "u" and its common ratio "r".

What I'd like to know is if i should solve this problem recursively or iteratively, I've read a lot of posts on when to choose recursion and when to choose iteration but they were pretty unclear.

PS: The compiler I use supports tail-recursion.

Comment: Personally, I'd choose an iterative algorithm any time a recursive one is not required.  In a recursive scenario, you should still consider if you control the call depth (e.g., if you control the data on which recursion happens); if you don't, you might have to validate the data and/or emulate recursion (e.g. using an explicit stack of items to process in an iterative algorithm).  Mind you, the compiler you're using **now** may support tail-recursion (and most implementations that do have subtleties that don't guarantee it like in Scheme), but what about tomorrow?  Also consider readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. Use the [explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).

PS.  The choice between iteration and recursion should be based on code readability and maintainability, not just speed:

> ... a computer language is not just a way of getting a computer to
>   perform operations, but rather ... it is a novel formal medium for
>   expressing ideas about methodology
>
> [Abelson/Sussman "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs"](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html).